# Unable to reproduce sum aggregate in MongoDB and C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

This MongoDB native query works just fine:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{hour:{$hour:'$CreatedAt'},day:{$dayOfMonth:'$CreatedAt'},month:{$month:'$CreatedAt'},year:{$year:'$CreatedAt'}}},
    {$group:{_id:{hour:'$hour',day:'$day',month:'$month',year:'$year'}, count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

...but when I try to reproduce the same query in C#, the result is 0 for every sum (which is not the case when running the native query in Robomongo).

This is the C# code. I am failing to see any differences between both...

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, Int32> GetSumPerHour()
{

    var project = new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "$project", 
            new BsonDocument{
            {"hour", new BsonDocument{{"$hour","$CreatedAt"}}},
            {"day", new BsonDocument{{"$dayOfMonth","$CreatedAt"}}},
            {"month", new BsonDocument{{"$month","$CreatedAt"}}},
            {"year", new BsonDocument{{"$year","$CreatedAt"}}},
            }
        }
    };

    var group = new BsonDocument 
    { 
        { 
            "$group", 
            new BsonDocument 
                { 
                    {"_id", new BsonDocument {{"hour","$hour"},{"day","$day"},{"month","$month"},{"year","$year"}}}, 
                    {"count", new BsonDocument {{"$sum","1"}} }
                } 
        } 
    };

    var pipeline = new[] { project, group };
    var arguments = new AggregateArgs { Pipeline = pipeline };
    var results = this.collection.Aggregate(arguments);

    var timeValueDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, Int32>();

        foreach (BsonDocument result in results)
        {

            int hour = result["_id"]["hour"].AsInt32;
            int day = result["_id"]["day"].AsInt32;
            int month = result["_id"]["month"].AsInt32;
            int year = result["_id"]["year"].AsInt32;

            DateTime time = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0);
            int count = result["count"].AsInt32;

            timeValueDictionary.Add(time, count);

        }            

    return timeValueDictionary;

}
```

Comment: Umm "1" is shown as a string and not a number as the argument to `$sum`, so that's the problem. Also, better practice here to just submit all of this in a single `$group` statement. The server will optimize this, but it's unnecessary overhead to write in two stages.

Comment: yes! I really was totally unable to see this error... thank you. _ better practice here to just submit all of this in a single `$group` statement _ <= ok thanks I'll take a look at it